# Getting different source codes from http get and actual source code

Tags: node.js, http, get

Im having trouble with my web scraping that i need for my project.

It seems that I'm getting a different source than the actual source code.

This is my code :

```
var request = require("request");

request({
  url: "http://csgolounge.com/trade?t=96580981",
}, function(error, response, body) {
console.log(body);
});
```

And its just missing some parts.
For example :

```
 <div id="offer">
  <textarea placeholder="Add your message here... Reminder: only English in trade offers!" id="notes" class="message" name="message"></textarea>
  <form id="replyTo" style="display: none; min-height: 30px;"></form>
  <form class="left" style="display: none;width: 98%;margin: 8px 1%;"><input type="hidden" name="tslt" value="31369f8ed9ec5f92915aa1ae899b484c"></form>
  <a class="button" onclick="postReplay('98057741');$(this).hide();">Post reply</a>
  <a class="button" onclick="showBackpack();$(this).remove()">Add items to offer</a>
        <a class="buttonright" href="https://steamcommunity.com/tradeoffer/new/?partner=104198881&token=BpXaAtwA" target="_blank">Steam offer</a>
        <img src="http://cdn.dota2lounge.com/img/load.gif" id="loading" style="display: none; margin: 0.75em 2%" />
</div>
```

This whole part is just missing.

Im using node.js and the module request for my project.

Help is much appreciated.

Comment: So when you do a "View Page Source" you can see that div#offer, but when you do the http request you do not?

Comment: Yep , exactly. Even some other parts

Comment: There's always the possibility the server is detecting User-Agent or some other property of the request, and dispatching different content.  I don't believe anyone can know this without the server code (have it?).

Comment: Well , different parts of the site do work. At its seems quite random parts are missing

Comment: Is there a site login?  or site cookies?

Comment: Oh right ! I forgot it doesn't show it when you aren't in.Do you know how can you perform a sign in ? It's steam

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since there's a steam login, you won't get the same content as you would if you were logged in.

You can login either by using an API to directly login or by finding a login form on the site and sending that same type of data to the server the same way that it is sent when you login from a site web page.  To figure out how to login, you can probably just look at the network tab in Chrome when you login from a regular web page on the site and look at what it sends to the server (probably a form post) and then you can just mimic that with a request.

The login will then likely return a cookie that you will need to keep track of and then send with the rest of your requests which will give you the content that a logged in user will get.